# Mysql join with one to many relations

Tags: mysql

claims

```
c_id   claim id   
1       201
2       202
3       203
4       204
```

claim_status

```
cs_id   claim_id    status
1       201     created
2       202     created
3       202     submitted
4       203     submitted
5       204     created
```

**If the claim is created and submitted(like claim_id 202) it would not show up if i search with 'created' condition. this is my main requirement. i need result like below**
If i search with status='created' i need to get records as below

```
c_id    claim_id    cs_id   claim_id    status
1           201     1           201     created
4           204     5           204     created
```

If i search with status='submitted' i need to get records as below

```
c_id    claim_id    cs_id   claim_id    status
2           202     3           202     submitted
3           203     4           203     submitted
```

But i'm unable to achive my result with below query. I'm new to stackoverflow. so please forgive me if i'm wrong in clear posting.

SQL:

```
SELECT * from claims c 
INNER JOIN claim_status cs 
ON c.claim_id = cs.claim_id 
WHERE cs.status='created'  
GROUP BY cs.claim_id
```

Comment: ...and your question would be? (fyi: you only need to have this `cs.status='created'` once: in `ON` clause or `WHERE` clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get claims that are created but not submitted try this:

```
SELECT * from claims c 
INNER JOIN claim_status cs 
ON c.claim_id = cs.claim_id
WHERE cs.status='created'  
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM claim_status cs2
  WHERE cs2.claim_id = cs.claim_id
        AND cs2.status='submitted'
)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. It's working fine but having little doubt about the performance issue. Is it ok in performance wise?

Comment: If you have an index on claim_id for both tables, it should be pretty good.

Comment: is there way to avoid two selects(query inside query) ?

Comment: I'm not seeing how you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

for 'created':

```
SELECT * from claims c 
INNER JOIN claim_status cs 
ON c.claim_id = cs.claim_id  
WHERE cs.status='created'
```

for 'submitted':

```
SELECT * from claims c 
INNER JOIN claim_status cs 
ON c.claim_id = cs.claim_id  
WHERE cs.status='submitted'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are those your actual tables? why are you handling claim statuses on another table than claims? You should have a "status" column on "claims" and you are done. You could have another table for versioning (if you want to get older states of the claim) and save changes, timestamps, etc, but for the current status is much better to have that on the same table

I know it's not the answer you are asking, but I think it's better to have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM claims WHERE status = 'created'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM claims WHERE status = 'submitted'
```

It's faster, cleaner, better, everything (?)

Also, to make them even faster, status should be an integer column and "created" should have an associated number so you can do

```
SELECT * FROM claims WHERE status = <value that means created>
```

the same for submitted or any extra status

Comment: can you put a "status" column on claims? that claim_status table is pointless. You are repeating the claim ID on another table and adding complexity to your query, if you have no specific need for that table I think you should go with status on claims table